# Does the ESP32's Long Range capability work with most smartphones?

Tags: wifi, esp32, long-distance

Recently discovered an ESP32 can be [its own access point](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-access-point-ap-web-server/) (controlling or displaying data wirelessly through a web browser not connected to Internet). It also has long-range capability:

**Long Range (LR)**

> Long Range (LR) mode is an Espressif-patented Wi-Fi mode which can achieve a one-kilometer line of sight range. It has better reception sensitivity, stronger anti-interference ability and longer transmission distance than the traditional 802.11B mode.

**LR Compatibility**

> Since LR is Espressif unique Wi-Fi mode, only ESP32 devices can transmit and receive the LR data. In other words, the ESP32 device should NOT transmit the data in LR data rate if the connected device doesn’t support LR. The application can achieve this by configuring suitable Wi-Fi mode. If the negotiated mode supports LR, the ESP32 may transmit data in LR rate, otherwise, ESP32 will transmit all data in traditional Wi-Fi data rate.

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/wifi.html

Or what smartphones cannot receive LR data? Further on that page, "For LR enabled in ESP32 station and the mode is NOT LR only mode, it’s compatible with traditional 802.11 mode." So it appears like it will work...

I will probably test to see how slow the data sends for a 1/2 mile with line of sight and perhaps 1/4 mile or as far as possible in a woodland.

Side question, is this [LR](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/4297) the same as [LoRa](https://www.instructables.com/ESP32-Long-Distance-LoRaWan/)?

Answer (score 2):

No, LR is not the same as LoRa. No, your smartphone will not be able to use this LR mode. As you quoted yourself:

> LR is Espressif unique Wi-Fi mode, only ESP32 devices can transmit and
> receive the LR data.

Comment: "For LR enabled in ESP32 station and the mode is NOT LR only mode, it’s compatible with traditional 802.11 mode." So what does that mean then??

Comment: I think it means that the device switches to common 802.11 (non-LR) operation.

Comment: So is the idea to have ESP32s in a mesh network? Why have LR capability? Perhaps a desktop computer can be configured to receive LR?

Comment: `Perhaps a desktop computer can be configured to receive LR?` ... not necessarily ... use an ESP32 as a gateway ... connect it to the computer using a cable

Comment: @adamaero "only ESP32 devices can transmit and receive the LR data" If you want to receive the data with a laptop you will need to connect an ESP32 device to the laptop.